# help with use of functional dependencies

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies

I have a question about functional dependencies. My understanding was that, for example, if I write `class Graph g a b | g -> a, g -> b`, then any specific `g` can be associated with only one type of `a` and `b`. Indeed, trying to declare two instance with the same `g` and different `a` and `b` does not work.

However, the compiler (ghc) seems unable to use the dependency in the following case,

```
class (Eq a, Eq b) => Graph g a b | g -> a, g -> b where
    edges :: g -> [b]
    src :: g -> b -> a
    dst :: g -> b -> a

    vertices :: g -> [a]
    vertices g = List.nub $ map (src g) (edges g) ++ map (dst g) (edges g)

class Graph g a b => Subgraph g a b | g -> a, g -> b where
    extVertices :: g -> [b]

data Subgraph1 g where
    Subgraph1 :: Graph g a b => g -> [b] -> Subgraph1 g

instance Graph g a b => Graph (Subgraph1 g) a b where
    vertices (Subgraph1 g _) = vertices g
    edges (Subgraph1 g _) = edges g
    src (Subgraph1 g _) = src g
    dst (Subgraph1 g _) = dst g
```

If I revise `Subgraph1` by adding the parameters `a` and `b` to the type signature, then everything works out.

```
data Subgraph1 g a b where
    Subgraph1 :: Graph g a b => g -> [b] -> Subgraph1 g a b
```

Comment: You need to use an associated type rather than an MPTC and fundep to avoid having the edge type infect your Subgraph type's signature. This is one small part of why they were invented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use fundeps, they are too much pain. Use associated types.

```
class (Eq (Vertex g), Eq (Edge g)) => Graph g where
  type Edge   g :: *
  type Vertex g :: *

  edges :: g -> [Edge g]
  src   :: g -> Edge g -> Vertex g
  dst   :: g -> Edge g -> Vertex g

  vertices :: g -> [Vertex g]
  vertices g = nub $ map (src g) (edges g) ++ map (dst g) (edges g)

class Graph g => Subgraph g where
  extVertices :: g -> [Edge g]

data Subgraph1 g where
    Subgraph1 :: Graph g => g -> [Edge g] -> Subgraph1 g

instance Graph g => Graph (Subgraph1 g) where
    type Edge (Subgraph1 g) = Edge g
    type Vertex (Subgraph1 g) = Vertex g
    vertices (Subgraph1 g _) = vertices g
    edges (Subgraph1 g _) = edges g
    src (Subgraph1 g _) = src g
    dst (Subgraph1 g _) = dst g
```

This looks somewhat more readable. `Edge g` is the type of `g`'s edges, etc.

Note that I translated your code mechanically, without understanding what Subgraph1 does. Why do you need a GADT here, and what the second argument of the data constructor means? It is not used anywhere.

Comment: Nice, that looks beautiful! I read about these but haven't used them yet. The GADT was used to say that only types _g_ which were graphs could be used to construct `Subgraph1`.